# Weird Issue with getActivity and Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

When I build the app using studio it works fine. and then I close the app then open the app using app icon in device `getactivity()` becomes `null` and crashes. 
If I run again after crashing the app runs fine.

Does anyone have faced this issue.

Instance 1:

```
  mCustomListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainContainerFragment.this.getActivity(), cardsModelArrayList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mCustomListAdapter);
// Crashing at  mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Instance 2 Crash :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: you need to include your code on where you are using `getActivity()` method call.

Comment: that depends on where you use getActivity()

Comment: Code pasted and these are called on oncreateview() of fragment

Answer (score 0):

Change this from

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Which line you'r getting NPE?

Comment: Now its crashing at <code>SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();</code>